# This operation has been disabled in the command-map and cannot be used: AUTH: RedisCommandException

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I have the below code to setup the Sentinel Redis connection.

```
var redisConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(redisSettingsJsonSection).Get<EightRedisConfiguration>();

    var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                ServiceName = redisConfiguration.ServiceName,
                TieBreaker = string.Empty,
                DefaultVersion = new Version(
                    redisConfiguration.DefaultVersionMajor,
                    redisConfiguration.DefaultVersionMinor,
                    redisConfiguration.DefaultVersionBuild),
                Password = redisConfiguration.Password,
                AbortOnConnectFail = redisConfiguration.AbortOnConnectFail,
                Ssl = redisConfiguration.Ssl,
                AllowAdmin = redisConfiguration.AllowAdmin,
                ConnectTimeout = redisConfiguration.ConnectTimeout,
                DefaultDatabase = redisConfiguration.Database
            };

            foreach (var redisHost in redisConfiguration.Hosts)
            {
                configOptions.EndPoints.Add(redisHost.Host, redisHost.Port);
            }

            configOptions.CommandMap = redisConfiguration.IsSentinelCluster ? CommandMap.Sentinel : CommandMap.Default;

            services.AddSingleton(_ =>
                    ConnectionMultiplexer
                        .Connect(configOptions, logTextWriter)
                        .GetSentinelMasterConnection(configOptions));
```

I receive the following exception.

```
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& hasNoDefaultCtor)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
This operation has been disabled in the command-map and cannot be used: AUTH: RedisCommandException
   at StackExchange.Redis.CommandMap.AssertAvailable(RedisCommand command) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/CommandMap.cs:line 169
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer..ctor(ConfigurationOptions configuration) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1141
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(Object configuration, LogProxy log, EventHandler`1& connectHandler) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 958
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(Object configuration, TextWriter log) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1014
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1002
```

The configuration is the below.

```
"DefaultVersionMajor": 4,
    "DefaultVersionMinor": 0,
    "DefaultVersionBuild": 11,
    "ServiceName": "eight-sentinel",
    "IsSentinelCluster": true,
    "Password": "AWESOME_PASSWORD",
    "AllowAdmin": true,
    "Ssl": false,
    "ConnectTimeout": 3000,
    "ConnectRetry": 2,
    "Database": 0,
    "Hosts": [
      {
        "Host": "redis-1.com",
        "Port": 26379
      },
      {
        "Host": "redis-2.com",
        "Port": 26379
      },
      {
        "Host": "redis-3.com",
        "Port": 26379
      }
    ]
```

I'm a bit lost with the issue and not sure the message behind it, I can connect using Redis Desktop Manager client to the sentinel cluster with just adding the first instance.

Comment: I also have the same problem, have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a similar issue and after some research, I realized they have some issues in the library, seems like there is an issue with using `ConfigurationOptions`.

As it suggested [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1580)
, it works if you create a connection via connection string instead

```
using(var connection=new ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("10.1.3.11:26379,10.1.3.12:26379,10.1.3.13:26379,serviceName=redis-primary,AllowAdmin=true"))
{
// do stuff
}
```

you have to specify `ServiceName` in the connection string in order to connect to Sentinel.

They introduced a new method `SentinelConnect` which doesn't work with the same connection string!

if you are using `StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core` library which doesn't have a constructor with connection string you should create an empty instance of RedisConfiguration and in ConnectionPoolManager implementation connect via ConnectionString.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Will definitely use this if we revisit Sentinel. At the moment I am using RedisLabs since my caching requirements are super low.